# Could not find a declaration file for module ‘fawn’ in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, npm, require

I am trying to install npm module Fawn into my NodeJS file. I have installed it in my root directory of my project file. It is loaded into my root directory node_module folder.

However when I try to load it into my project file, I am getting the following error: Could not find a declaration file for module ‘fawn’.

```
const Fawn = require(‘fawn’);
```

Has anyone had this same issue? Any help is much appreciated!

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: Is your project a TypeScript project?

Comment: Did you restarted your node server?

Comment: It is a JavaScript project. I did restart my node server.

Comment: VS Code tells me my fawn.js file implicitly has an 'any' type. I am not sure how to fix that. I am still learning nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

For the importing JS module in the typescript, you should have the typings file as well. Commonly it's declared in the package or can be installed like this: `npm i -D @types/package-name`. However, for this module, it's not available and the author isn't planning to add this: https://github.com/e-oj/Fawn/issues/57 . You can create your d.ts file for this library and declare required types there: https://www.ankursheel.com/blog/custom-type-definitions-for-java-script-dependencies

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Javascript.

Comment: well, the error that you provided is the TS one. Could you share the exact screenshot?

Comment: your IDE considers it as a TS project. It might be an IDE setup or some .tsconfig file in the directory above.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Fawn.init('mongodb://localhost/vidly');     
    try{
        new Fawn.Task()
        .update('movies', { _id: movie._id }, {
            $inc: { numberInStock: -1 }
        })
        .save('rentals', rental)
        
        .run()
        res.send(rental)
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex)
    }
```

try to add a database link instead of a mongoose. this worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).